# avoid values beyond a fixed range with

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to avoid the inserction of data outside the interval (-1, 1), for the iscriz field, and (0,10) for the giudizio field.

```
CREATE TABLE pa (
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_ID int,
FOREIGN KEY (user_ID) 
REFERENCES user(ID),   
evento_ID int,
FOREIGN KEY (evento_ID) 
REFERENCES evento(ID),
iscriz int, 
CONSTRAINT iscriz CHECK (iscriz >-2 AND iscriz <2), 
giudizio int, 
CONSTRAINT giudizio CHECK (giudizio >-1 AND giudizio <11), 
PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

Aldo I tried with

```
...
iscriz int, 
CHECK (iscriz >-2 AND iscriz <2), 
giudizio int, 
CHECK (giudizio >-1 AND giudizio <11),
```

I had not a syntax error, but it doens't work.

I can insert new values as:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO pa  (user_ID, evento_ID, iscriz, giudizio)  VALUES    ( "1", "3", "1", "18"),  ( "2", "3", "0", "17"), ( "3", "3", "-1", "16"), ( "4", "3", "7", "15");
```

Thanks, 
Andrea

Comment: You need to use triggers.  Although MySQL accepts the syntax for `check` constraints, it doesn't actually implement them.

Comment: Ok, I'll read this [link] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html . But, it's really wired that "MySQL doesn't actually implement them."

Comment: . . If it is any consolation, almost every other database supports `check` constraints.